# Binding help XAML Xamarin Forms .net2.0 app

Tags: c#, xamarin, data-binding, binding, xamarin.forms

I have some XAML

```
<Label x:Name="AYCOBRO" Text="{Binding COBRO}" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
```

The cs page/ code page behind the XAML gets the binding context set with:

```
    BindingContext = new UIBindingProperties();
```

a separate class called UIBindingProperties.cs where I define my properties. Here i tried to implement INotifyPropertyChanged but i think it's not correct as so:

```
public class UIBindingProperties : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
         public string COBRO
        {
            get
            {
                return COBRO;
            }
            set
            {
                COBRO = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(COBRO));
            }
        }
    }
```

Now from a background worker class I'm trying to update the property to be reflected in the UI with:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                var t = new UIBindingProperties();
                t.COBRO = amounttopay;

//I can see the property being set with this //
                Debug.WriteLine("your COBRO propertie is: " + t.COBRO); 

            });
```

Nothing happens. What is wrong here?

**UPDATE:**

Started to use Refractored.MvvmHelpers nuget and my UIBindingProperties class looks now like this:

```
public class UIBindingProperties : BaseViewModel
    {
        private string cobro;
        public string COBRO
        {
            get => cobro;
            set => SetProperty(ref cobro, value);
        }
    }
```

Still no success...

UPDATE 2 in addition to the accepted answer below instead i added to the app.xaml.cs

```
public static UIBindingProperties viewModel = new UIBindingProperties();
```

with this i can access this viewmodel app-wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to reinvent the wheel. Check out the [MvvmHelpers](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers) by James Montemagno and use the `BaseViewModel` as a base class for your `UIBindingProperties`

To be more clear. Add [MvvmHelpers NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Refractored.MvvmHelpers/) to your project and use `BaseViewModel`, which implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged`, as follows

```
public class UIBindingProperties : BaseViewModel
{
    private string name;    
    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set => SetProperty(ref name, value);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I've just noticed that you're creating a new object `var t = new UIBindingProperties()`. Which means you're now working with completely different object then the one you have set as your `ViewModel` (i.e. object set as your `BindingContext`). Create a field for your `ViewModel` (i.e. `UIBindingProperties`), assign it to the `BindingContext` of your page and then update the property on **the same** object. The code could look something like this:

```
public class MainPage
{
    private UIBindingProperties viewModel = new UIBindingProperties();

    public MainPage()
    {
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }

    public void SomeMethodInvokedLater()
    {
        viewModel.COBRO = "Completely different value than the initial one";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it. There must be a simple solution to my code though.

Comment: If you don't want to install that NuGet, have a look at the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers/blob/master/MvvmHelpers/ObservableObject.cs) implementation - it definitely works

Comment: yes. thanks. I had a look, as well as many examples. I can't wrap my head around the two strings being set. the private and the public. Which is for what? which of those do i need to set from the code? Which one relates to the binding? I'm a bit lost on that part.

Comment: You should always work with the Property (the public one). That's because in the Setter (i.e. `set`) you should have the logic to handle raising the property change event (i.e. `OnPropertyChanged)` - that's what informs the UI that there has been a change and UI needs to retrieve the value again (i.e. update itself). In the sample code that I provided, `OnPropertyChanged` event is being raised in the `SetProperty` method code.

Comment: Yeah, instead of spending circles trying to work out why your `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation doesn't work, just use existing one and continue coding :)

Comment: Check out the EDIT part of my answer

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. How can I access the viewmodel now from a class in a different file?

Comment: Great. I set the viewmodel global in my app.xaml.cs now and can access it like that from everywhere. thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I'm glad that I could help. I would suggest, for the future development, have a look at some MVVM frameworks, like MVVM Light, [MvvmCross](https://www.mvvmcross.com/) or [Prism](https://prismlibrary.github.io/), which would help you with handling MVVM part of your project, navigation, IoC and many more. Have a read about these and other options.